# Spring Security - How to access v2 API using basic HTTP authentication in Hybris?

Tags: spring, web-services, tomcat, spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to access `v2` API using basic authentication(username/password), I have done all below-mentioned changes. But when I hit the web service URL, I'm getting a popup for providing username/password which is not taking(validating) my username/password. I'm sure I have entered correct username & password.

**web.xml:**

```
<security-role>
<description>
The role that is required to access the application
</description>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>RestrictedWebResource</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
<role-name>admin</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
<user-data-constraint>
<!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
<transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

**security-v2-spring.xml:**

```
<security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">      <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest/*" access="admin" />
<security:http-basic />
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager>
<security:authentication-provider>
<security:user-service>
<security:user name="ash" password="ash" authorities="admin" />
</security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

**tomcat-users.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="ash" password="ash" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

**config/local.properties:**

```
hybris.security.http.basic.auth.enable=true
hybris.security.http.basic.auth.username=ash
hybris.security.http.basic.auth.password=ash
```

tomcat-users.xml location is correctly configured in server.xml also

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
description="User database that can be updated and saved"
factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

The endpoint URL which I try to access is

```
https://localhost:9002/rest/v2/**/**/**
```

Usual admin console admin/nimda also doesn't work. I'm breaking my head in this for more than a week now. Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide endpoint URL you're trying to access, also try with admin/nimda once.

Comment: Yes I have added the endpoint URL & edited the question.

Comment: `v2` version is the default, which is based on `Auth2`, you need to add OAuth client in the system(using backoffice) to access `v2` API. Is this your requirement to access `v2` on basic auth? otherwise, without any code change, you can access it.

Comment: Yes, my requirement is to access v2 services using basic auth. I am not using OAuth which is available out of the box.

Comment: @Aswin,Did you had a chance to find an answer for this? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

From the URL it appears as if you are trying to access the *OCC API*.
Access to *OCC* has nothing to do with the regular authentication.
You need to create an *OAuth Client* using `OAuthClientDetails` model and give it appropriate *authorization*.
***Sample***-

```
INSERT_UPDATE OAuthClientDetails;clientId[unique=true];resourceIds;scope;authorizedGrantTypes;clientSecret;authorities
                                ;abc;hybris;basic;authorization_code,refresh_token,password,client_credentials;password;ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT
```